# Cambiar dataset de un botón HTML dinámicamente con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero poder lograr cambiar el `dataset` de un botón dinámicamente al ejecutar una función de acuerdo al activo presionado obteniendo su `id`.

Anexo el código para mejorar la compresión del problema:

```js
// Función que despliega un modal sencillo de múltiples activos (Botones, entidades)
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".viewAttributes").click(function() {
    /* este valor cambia de acuerdo al activo que presionaste
    ES EL VALOR QUE NECESITO CAMBIAR DINAMICAMENTE EN EL DATASET DEL HTML*/
    var id_activo = $(this).data("id") || "0";

    /* **CODIGO JS SIN ENFOQUE CREANDO UNA TABLA**
    Append para ya mandar la tabla al html */
    $("#table_attributes").empty().append(html);
  });
});
```

Del lado **HTML**, donde se encuentra el botón, está de esta manera:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <table
    class="table table-hover table-striped table-hover table-responsive-lg " id="attributeActivoTable">
    <thead class="text-uppercase text-dark font-weight-bold">
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th scope="col">Titulo</th>
        <th scope="col">Contenido</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="table_attributes" class="text-center">
      <!--Imprime la tabla generada por Javascript-->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pr-2" data-dismiss="modal">
      Cancelar
    </button>

    <!--BOTÓN QUE NECESITO CAMBIAR EL DATASET DE ACTIVO
    La clase editAttribute sirve para abrir un modal y en la función detectar el id de acuerdo a su dataset-->
    <input type="button" id="editAttribute" class="btn btn-primary buttonEvent editAttribute" data-activo="" value="Editar Valores del Template" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Al presionar el botón **HTML** debió haber capturado `data-activo` que anteriormente identificó dinámicamente.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".editAttribute").click(function() {
    var idActivo = $(this).data('activo') || '0';
    console.log(idActivo);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### La propiedad `dataset`

Partiendo de lo que planteas en tu pregunta, cito:

> "Quiero poder lograr cambiar el `dataset` de un botón dinámicamente al ejecutar una función de acuerdo al activo presionado obteniendo su `id`..."

Y partiendo del fragmento de código:

> ```js
> $(".viewAttributes").click(function() {
>   var id_activo = $(this).data('id') || '0';;
>   ...
> });
> ```

Además de éste:

> ```js
> $(".editAttribute").click(function() {
>   var idActivo = $(this).data("activo") || "0";
>   ...
> });
> ```

Se entiende que lo que lo que deseas lograr es que el valor del atributo `data-id` de la propiedad `dataset` de los elementos que contenga la clase `.viewAttributes`, al presionarse sobre uno de ellos se asigne el valor al atributo `data-activo` de la propiedad `dataset` del botón.

Esto se puede lograr realizando el siguiente cambio:

```js
$( ".viewAttributes" ).on( "click", function() {
  editAttribute.dataset.activo = $( this ).data( "id" );
});
```

Ten en cuenta que en el fragmento anterior de código **editAttribute** es el `id` del botón al que se le quiere cambiar el valor del atributo `data-activo`, es decir, `id="editAttribute"`.

#### Entendiendo un poco `dataset`

Para acceder desde **JavaScript** a los atributos de la propiedad `dataset` de un elemento dado, como por ejemplo:

```html
<div id="elemento" data-elemento-html="valor"></div>
```

Debe realizarlo siguiendo el *estilo* **camelCase:**

```js
elemento.dataset.elementoHtml;
```

Donde `elementoHtml` es, en el código **HTML** ,`elemento-html`; mientras que en **jQuery** se haría de la siguiente manera:

```js
$( "#elemento" ).data( 'elemento-html' );
```

#### Reproduciendo ejemplo

El fragmento de código publicado más abajo, en el ejemplo que se ejecutará, contará con **código CSS** que se utilizará solo con fines ilustrativos para permitirle visualizar que efectivamente se ha hecho la selección de un elemento dado.

Debe seleccionar uno de los elementos y luego presionar el botón **Editar Valores del Template** para visualizar los resultados.

Además se recomienda, tras presionar el botón **Ejecutar** hacer clic en el enlace «Página completa» del **Snippet** que sigue más abajo.

**Fragmento de código:**

```js
$(function() {
  $ ( ".viewAttributes" ).on( "click", function() {
    // Cambiando el valor de los atributos de la propiedad
    // dataset del elemento:
    editAttribute.dataset.activo = $( this ).data( 'id');
    
    // Estas dos (02) líneas sólo son relevantes en la ilustración:
    $( ".viewAttributes" ).removeClass( 'selected' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
  });
  
  // Mostrar los resultados en la consola al presionar
  // el botón:
  editAttribute.onclick = function() {
    console.log( "data-activo=\"" + this.dataset.activo + "\"" );
  };
});
```

```css
/* 
  Estos estilos solamente son relevantes
  para fines ilustrativos. Es decir, permitirle
  visualizar que efectivamente ha seleccionado 
  el elemento
*/
   
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.viewAttributes {
  background-color: silver;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #006ab0;
  color: white;
  transition: 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Asumiendo que son los activos con un data-id -->
<div class="viewAttributes" data-id="1">data-id="1" | Presione aquí y luego «Editar Valores del Template»</div>
<div class="viewAttributes" data-id="2">data-id="2" | Presione aquí y luego «Editar Valores del Template»</div>
<div class="viewAttributes" data-id="3">data-id="3" | Presione aquí y luego «Editar Valores del Template»</div>

<hr>

<!-- Botón al que se le cambiará el «dataset» -->
<button id="editAttribute" data-activo="">Editar Valores del Template</button>
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> Se omite código irrelevante en el problema. Solo se tomó en cuenta el código mínimo necesario para entender cómo resolver el problema planteado.

Puede consultar las siguientes fuentes, publicada en la página oficial de **Mozilla MDN** para ampliar un poco sobre la propiedad `dataset`:

- [HTMLElement.dataset - Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- [Utilizando atributos data (en inglés) - Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Completisima respuesta!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo, por el tiempo, esfuerzo que invertiste para responderme, se agradece, he podido solucionarlo con tu ayuda.